# Double values not adding together

Tags: java

I have 2 values which I'm trying to add together. Attempting so does not add the decimal place to the value.

```
int pearInt = (int) Double.parseDouble(pear.getText());
int appleInt = (int) Double.parseDouble(apple.getText());

double result = pearInt + appleInt;

total.setText("" +  result);
```

`pear.getText()` & `apple.getText()` is retrieving from a text field with the values `35.5` and `16.5`. When I try add them together, I want it to display `52.0` but it's displaying `51.0`

Comment: If you step through your code in your debugger you would be able to see that when you cast to `int` values you drop the fractions.  If you don't want to do this, take out the cast and use `double`.

Comment: What do you think the difference between an `int` and a `double` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your sum is of 2 ints:

```
int pearInt = (int) Double.parseDouble(pear.getText());
int appleInt = (int) Double.parseDouble(apple.getText());
```

This will produces 2 ints, because you are casting the doubles. So simply change to:

```
double pearInt = Double.parseDouble(pear.getText());
double appleInt = Double.parseDouble(apple.getText());
```

And you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Because you cast your doubles to int. Casting a floating point value to an integer will result in dropping everything behind the dot.
Thus you actualy calculate  35 +16